# Create Azure AD B2C local account user with Powershell New-AzureADUser

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to create a local user in an Azure AD B2C directory which can be used for authentication immediately after creation.

```
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $targetB2cTenant

$passwordProfile = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PasswordProfile
$passwordProfile.Password = "Test-User-Password-Here"
$userName = "TestUser@MyTestB2CTenant.onmicrosoft.com"    
$signInNames = @(
    (New-Object `
        Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.SignInName `
        -Property @{Type = "userName"; Value = $userName})
)

$newUser = New-AzureADUser -AccountEnabled $True -DisplayName "testpowershellusercreation" -PasswordProfile $passwordProfile -SignInNames $signInNames -CreationType "LocalAccount"

Disconnect-AzureAD
```

From reading the documentation I need to specify the CreationType parameter as "LocalAccount":

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0

[Creating a B2C user with MFA that can immediately login](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49034682)

However when I run the powershell code I receive the following error:

```
New-AzureADUser : Error occurred while executing NewUser 
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: One or more properties contains invalid values.
```

This error message is not present when I remove the -CreationType parameter.

What is the correct way to create a local account in a B2C directory using Powershell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sign-in name of **type** "userName" can't contain the '@' character in the **value** property.

i.e. You can't set it to an email address.

You might want to also set the following parameters for the new user:

```
$passwordProfile = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PasswordProfile
$passwordProfile.ForceChangePasswordNextLogin = $False
$passwordProfile.Password = "<Password>"

$newUser = New-AzureADUser ... -PasswordPolicies "DisablePasswordExpiration"
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. Although it would create the user once I corrected the username it would not let me sign in using the account unless I re-created the user with the PasswordPolicies "DisablePasswordExpiration" parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could also change the type of sign-in name from "userName" to "email", to work around this issue and allow users to continue using their foreign domain email addresses as login, if required.

```
$signInNames = (
    (New-Object `
        Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.SignInName `
        -Property @{Type = "email"; Value = "pstesta@fsdfsd.com"})
)
```

Comment: i think the type should be "emailAddress" instead.